# Express POST request body outputting unidentified and {}

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post

I am difficulty retrieving the body of an express post request form a HTML form. In my code I attempt to extract it normally raw and with JSON.stringify. Still no dice, just outputs:""Body: "undefined" received in app.js! ------- Body: "[object Object]" received in app.js!"" and the console outputs undefined and {}. Any help is appreciated. Bellow is both my JS code and HTML code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const path = require('path');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
})

app.post('/submit-form', function(req, res) {

    var x = req.body.key;
    var y = req.body;

    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(y));
    
    res.send(`Body: "${x}" recieved in app.js! ------- Body: "${y}" recieved in app.js!`);

})

app.listen(4001, function() {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 4001...");
})
```

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sample Site</title>

  <style>
    body { padding-top: 50px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>res.sendFile() Works!</h1>
      
      <form method="POST" action="/submit-form", body= "key: 'hellow wolrd'"}>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of a POST request is determined by the values of the named form controls (`input`, `select`, etc elements) in the form.

There is no `body` attribute for the `<form>` element.

[MDN has a forms + express tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms) that I recommend you read.

```
 <form method="POST" action="/submit-form">
     <input name=key value="hello, world">
     <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, just tested and this works. I notice that if i delete the <input> line the text box goes away. Is there anyway I can remove the text box but still have the submit button pass a static value I would define. For example Im making a rock paper scissors game and I want a button for each option.

Comment: @AdamSpera you could try adding `type='hidden'` to the input element.

Comment: Give each submit button a name and value. Don't use hidden inputs.